# R function save() unexpectedly writes to cloud

Tags: r, save, cloud

Working with a R project using RStudio.  getwd() shows I am well and truly in the project.  I used save() to write a file to the data subdirectory.  I used load() to successfully recover the file.  However when I looked the files were nowhere to be seen.  Eventually I found them in the cloud in the documents folder.  How does that happen?  How do I defeat it?

save(object, file="~/data/my_filename")
load(file="~/data/my_filename")          # works correctly

getwd() # looks correct

Why do the files end up in the cloud folder 'documents'.

I expected save() to write to the directory as shown by getwd().  Insteaad it goes to the cloud documents folder.

Comment: What does `path.expand(“~”)` return?

Comment: I'm guessing a bit here, but `~` is your home directory. Depending on your Windows setup this might be set as your OneDrive account.

Comment: @IRTFM - I assume you mean `path.expand("~")` without the smart quotes.

Comment: Since my iPhone seems  only capable of creating an ordinary dbl-quote with difficulty , it should’ve been `path.expand('~’)`. I am able to get backticks with extra thumb strokes and also apparently need to hold down the “-key to get "

Answer (score 1):

Pilot Error.  "~" indeed expands to the cloud.  Please do not take my linux card away.  The whole time I saw "~" as "."

path.expand() did the trick.

So who thought it was a good idea to set "~" to the cloud?